# i have a post call with 3 parameters (image,id,type)i need to send to server ,how can i send in retrofit. im using multipart but it won't let me in

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

I'm sending request like this

```
 public interface iUpload{
    @Multipart
    @POST("/uploadmultiplepropimages")
    SamplePojoClass getUploadData(
            @Part("prop_id") MultipartBody.Part prop_id,
            @Part("type") MultipartBody.Part type,
            @Part("prop_photos") MultipartBody.Part prop_photos
    );
}
```

Here is my declaration and call the response method

```
RequestBody lRidd = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "10000001");
        RequestBody lRtype = 
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "single");

        RequestBody lRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), photoFile);
        MultipartBody.Part lFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("prop_photos", photoFile.getName(), lRequestBody);
        MultipartBody.Part idd = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("prop_id", "10000001");
        MultipartBody.Part type = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("type", "single");
uploadImageResponse = RequestResponse.getUploadData(idd,type,lFile);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
private final WebApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(WebApi.class);





public void createGoal(String goalTitle, String goalDueDate, String goalComment, String goalCategory, String goalReminderDate, String account, File image, String userId, final CreateGoalHandler handler) {

        if (image != null) {
            RequestBody requestBodies = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), image);
            part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profileImage", image.getName(), requestBodies);
        }

        RequestBody goalTtle = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), goalTitle);
        RequestBody goalDueDte = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), goalDueDate);
        RequestBody goalCmnt = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), goalComment);
        RequestBody goalCtgry = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), goalCategory);
        RequestBody goalReminderDtes = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), goalReminderDate);
        RequestBody accnt = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), account);
        RequestBody userid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), userId);


        Call<CreateGoalPrp> callback = api.createGoal(goalTtle, goalDueDte, goalCmnt, goalCtgry, goalReminderDtes, accnt, part, userid);
        callback.enqueue(new Callback<CreateGoalPrp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CreateGoalPrp> call, Response<CreateGoalPrp> response) {
                handler.OnSuccess(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CreateGoalPrp> call, Throwable t) {
                handler.OnSuccess(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

//////////////////////////////

```
public interface WebApi {

    @Multipart
    @POST("createGoal.php")
    Call<CreateGoalPrp> createGoal(@Part("goalTitle") RequestBody goalTitle, @Part("goalDueDate") RequestBody goalDueDate, @Part("goalComment") RequestBody goalComment, @Part("goalCategory") RequestBody goalCategory, @Part("goalReminderDate") RequestBody goalReminderDate, @Part("account") RequestBody account, @Part MultipartBody.Part profileImage, @Part("userId") RequestBody userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your interface called EmployeeAPI

```
@Multipart
@POST("/Home/UploadProfilePic")
void UploadFile(@Part("file")TypedFile file, @Part("StaffIDNO")String StaffIDNO, Callback<Response> callback);
```

The function takes 2 arguments a file and a string.

Call the method in your activity using the following function

```
public void UploadFile(final TypedFile file, final String StaffId) {

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
       final  GlobalRecordFetch globalRecordFetch = new GlobalRecordFetch(getActivity());
        builder.setEndpoint(globalRecordFetch.ROOT_URL);
        builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        EmployeeAPI api = restAdapter.create(EmployeeAPI.class);
        api.UploadFile(
                file,
                StaffId,
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        String output = "";
                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                            output = reader.readLine();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                    }
                }
        );


    }
```